# PHP imagettftext invalid font filename

Tags: php, gd, truetype

I am trying to create an image with text by using imagettftext. It is telling me Warning: imagettftext(): Invalid font filename in C:\xampp\htdocs\recentpost.php on line 32. Here is the code on line 32 I am using to add the text

```
imagettftext($img, 12, 0, 20, 1, $black, "../fonts/arial.ttf", "News!");
```

I copied the font right out of the C:/Windows/Fonts folder so it is a valid font.

Comment: Have you tried using the full path instead of the relative path?

Comment: Yes I have and it gave me the same error.

Comment: Take a look at the [manual for imagettftext](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php).  Under the explanation of the $fontfile parameter, it explains that, in some cases, if the file name doesn't begin with with a slash, ".ttf" is appended to that path.  Might that be causing issues?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try something like:

```
$font = dirname(__FILE__) . '/arial.ttf';
//OR
$font = dirname(__FILE__) . '/fonts/arial.ttf';    
imagettftext($img, 12, 0, 20, 1, $black, $font, "News!");
```

Comment: that means the font has to be in the same folder as the file correct? I haven't used dirname(__FILE__) before so I am not sure how that works at all

Comment: dirname actually returns parent directory's path, so you can place your font in fonts folder and use dirname as mentioned above, but the fonts folder should be inside your project folder

Comment: this is the only thing that has worked for me!

Comment: It requires an absolute path that's why this answer works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using

```
imagettftext($img, 12, 0, 20, 1, $black, "../fonts/arial.TTF", "News!");
```

instead? (.TTF instead of .ttf)

and @Fab, you can use both \ and / on windows.

Comment: Also, have you tried including the font from the root folder?

Answer (score 1):

Oh wow, stupid me... Its too late for me to be up working on php :p I was trying to get to get to a non existing folder. The real code should be

```
imagettftext($img, 12, 0, 20, 1, $black, "fonts/arial.ttf", "News!");
```

Thank you everyone for trying to fix my silly mistake :p

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, you should use `"..\fonts\arial.ttf"` as path I think

Comment: Just tried it and it doesn't work either. I don't get what is going on. I have xampp and I do believe its up to date. I have tried everything I can think of and every trick I have found online and just can't for the life of me get this to work. Although it is late at night and have been working on this for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use double slash:

```
imagettftext($img, 12, 0, 20, 1, $black, "..\\fonts\\arial.ttf", "News!");
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the suggestions above but none worked for me.

So, I will be adding what worked for me in case, someone else was in my shoes.

I used

```
imagettftext($img, 12, 0, 20, 1, $black, getcwd()."\fonts\\arial.ttf", "News!");
```

*Please note that the extra backslash before 'arial.ttf' is to escape the backslash in the original font file directory.*

`getcwd()` is used for getting the current working directory. You can read more [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php).

*You can use `echo getcwd()."\fonts\\arial.ttf"` to get the full directory and change all the backslash to forward slash if you wish. It will still work fine*